# Intellij IDEA 13.1 How to edit/create files and folders in remote machine on the fly

Tags: intellij-13

1 version,. and am trying to do the following..

In short  - Access remote machine and browse and EDIT on the fly i.e without creating a local copy. i.e i need to create a ftp connection and start editing the files, create folders etc on the fly

1. Access the Remote machine - which is working perfectly i.e am able to connect to remote machine
2. Now i need to browse the files and folders from the remote machine which is also working correctly [see IMAGE]
3. I need to do the following now .. just open the file ftpfile.tryit (having full permission) from remote machine on the main window and edit it DIRECTLY .. which am not able to perform, all am seeing is the following behavior

   - When i double-click there is no change/ nothing happens
   - When i rightclick, i need to copy the file to local machine (in my case it is mac) and then edit it.. which i do not want to do..

[image]

Comment: Post the images as links - if they are relevant we will edit the post and make them into images.

Comment: Image Link - http://imgur.com/5s9VBiC

Answer (score 2):

Under remote host configuration you can also see mapping tab, where you can to configure mapping between remote and local files. After you finish it, you can double click on file on remote machine and it must open local version, after you finish editing local version you can right-click on main editor window and choose option 'Sync with deployed to...'.
I hope it will help you.